# Comment appelle-t-on une « fausse rime » ?

Tags: poésie, rime

Je sais qu'il existe un nom qui désigne une *fausse rime*, c'est-à-dire l'utilisation d'un phonème qui ressemble à un autre sans être pourtant exactement le même.

Remarquable exemple :

> Une souris ver**te**
> Qui courrait dans l'her**be**
>
> Je l'attrappe par la **queue**
> Je la montre à ces mes**sieurs**
>
> Ces messieurs me di**sent**
> Trempez-la dans l'hui**le**
>
> Trempez-la dans **l'eau**
> Ça fera un escargot tout **chaud**

Quel est le nom de cette incongruité ?

**NOTE :** techniquement, la voyelle de la dernière syllabe n'est pas un *e* muet, mais comme la chanson accentue les fins de vers, j'ai mis en évidence des syllabes qui n'en sont pas vraiment, les puristes me pardonneront.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ce n'est pas une incongruité mais un type de versification, [l'assonance](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/assonance), plus précisément l'assonance métrique qui [prévalait en poésie jusqu'au XVIIe siècle](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assonance#Historique_de_la_notion).

> Une souris v**erte**
> Qui courrait dans l'h**erbe**
>
> Je l'attrappe par la **queue**
> Je la montre à ces mes**sieurs**
>
> Ces messieurs me d**isent**
> Trempez-la dans l'h**uile**
>
> Trempez-la dans **l'eau**
> Ça fera un escargot tout **chaud**